# parallax on section of the page, normal scrolling for the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery, parallax

I have a page, consistng of several sections. All of them (except from last one) have to take the whole height of the screen, with parallax scrolling, and the last one - have dynamic height, based on its content. The content is few times taller than the screen, and has to be scrolled normally.

`Here's codepen https://codepen.io/eagor/pen/MozVjo I've edited a bit to show what I need to achieve.` First 3 sections behave just like I need. The only thing to add - normal scrolling for the last section.

Answer (score 1):

You could go for something like

```
.background:nth-child(4) {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    ...
}
```

now you just need to redefine you transparent background.

Comment: thanks, it worked. But if you scroll fast in 3rd section, then the last section gets scrolled to bottom to. Any ideas, how to prevent it from happening? cancelling scroll event or smth? https://codepen.io/eagor/pen/weQLyG